# Why won't "Open .fxml file with Scene Builder 2.0" work on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I've seen similar questions on Stack Overflow for this issue and have tried their solutions but still did not work. Whenever I try to open a .fxml file with scene builder using the "Open with Scene Builder" option, nothing shows up. Not an error or anything, but the Scene Builder won't show up.

**Using**:

Eclipse Neon
Windows 10

**What I've tried** *based on Stack Overflow Answers*:

Open Scene Builder from desktop application,

```
Click File --> Preferences --> Reset to Builtin Default Values
then       --> Open Recent --> Clear Menu
```

Still though, I would have the same problem.

Comment: What does the fxml contain. Does something show up in the hierarchical/structural view?

Comment: when you double click on the file does it open in scene builder? but only in eclipse it doesnt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was rather silly and quite simple, GoXR3Plus' answer helped me with that. I had the paths already set but I didn't include the Scene Builder 2.0.exe program itself in the path, rather only the folder containing it.
If you're encountering the same problem, make sure your path contains the File.exe.
Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to set the path of the executable file of `SceneBuilder.exe` so **Eclipse** recognizes where to search the program that will open the `.fxml` file.

Also is seems strange using `SceneBuilder 2.0` when you can have the  briefly new [SceneBuilder 8](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/) that has more magic into it.

---

Setting the path on the preferences for `JavaFX`:

[image]

After that you can open the `.fxml` file just right clicking on it:

[image]